# string operations in Python using indexing

Tags: python, string

I have the following piece of code :

```
str1 = "abcd"
print(str1[1:9:3])
```

The answer I get is `"b"`

How is this being calculated. This means that in the string str1, print out the 3rd character from 1st position to 9th.
Hence str1[1:9] will be "bcd". And the third character in this should throw me an error. But instead I am getting "b". How is this ?

Comment: `3` is not the 3rd character. It is *every third*, starting at the start. `'abcdefg'[1::2]` would give me every second character from `b`, producing `'bdf'`.

Comment: You might want to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/4788274)...